# Solution for local ip changes of AWS EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Amazon only gives you a certain number of static ip address and the local (private) ips of each EC2 instance can change when the machine is restarted. This makes creating a stable platform where EC2 instances depend on each other ridiculously hard to use as far as I can tell.

I've search online a lot about various solutions and so far have found nothing reasonable outside of assigning an elastic ip address on ever EC2 even if its not public facing. Does anyone have any other good ideas that is actually easy to execute on?

Thanks!

See the AWS team's response to question [Static local IP](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=207526):

> The internal IP address of EC2 instances is allocated via DHCP. On
>   instance shutdown, or when the DHCP lease expires, the IP address is
>   returned to the general EC2 DHCP pool of addresses available for other
>   instances.
>
> There is no way to guarantee that you will obtain the same DHCP
>   address across reboots.

**Edit:** The answer is to use Amazon VPC. There is no downside except a trivial amount of extra setup because now you control the router. It's a world apart from plain old EC2 instance on AWS. It's so necessary in fact that VPC will be enabled for all future AWS setups by default. See this post for more information: http://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/1a3n0r/ec2_update_virtual_private_clouds_for_everyone/

Comment: Is there a tutorial on exactly how to configure the Amazon VPC? I know nothing about it.

Comment: Miranda: read these. http://blog.engineering.kiip.me/post/12288961849/ec2-to-vpc-transition-worth-doing http://nineofclouds.blogspot.com/2013/01/vpc-migration-planning.html https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=126976

Comment: @Mauvis, How much does VPC cost?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The stock answers are:

1. Use [AWS VPC](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/) so you have complete control over instance addressing
2. Use Elastic IPs, which will resolve to the instance's *local* address (not the public, as you'd expect) when used to communicate between EC2 instances

Comment: Thanks gabrtv. Just a note here that AWS VPC doesn't work with micro instances. I'm using Kue to create a pub/sub worker queue and buying all small instances (at 4x the cost) isn't manageable. Looking at the other solutions.

Comment: Additionally, you are limited in how many Elastic IP's you can have. Our limit seems to be 10.

Comment: @MauvisLedford I believe the limit starts at 5.  However you can request more Elastic IPs here: http://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/eip_limit_request/

Comment: An update here that VPC now works with micro instances and I have a working VPC prototype with two instances. One publicly addressable via elastic ip and the other using local ip only and only communicable within my private network. This is truly the way to go. And best of all no additional charge to use.

Comment: One issue with Elastic IP is that when you shutdown then restart an instance, it does not automatically associate itself back to the original Elastic IP. So you have to deal with that too.

Comment: _"Use Elastic IPs, which will resolve to the instance's local address (not the public, as you'd expect) when used to communicate between EC2 instances"_ Major caveat: It only resolves like that if you use the Public DNS Name, not the Public IP address.

Comment: Which is unfortunate when your requirement is for an ip To be used not host name! Vpc it might have to be!

Answer (score 13):

I stumbled upon third option. There's [ec2-ssh](https://github.com/Instagram/ec2-ssh) by the Instragram folks. It's a python shell script that you install globally and lets you both query the public dns of your ec2 instances by tag name and also `ssh` in via tag name as well.

The documentation for it is virtually nonexistent. I've written down the steps to install below:

To install ec2-ssh:

1. `sudo yum install python-boto` (python wrapper for ec2 api)
2. git clone https://github.com/Instagram/ec2-ssh
3. In your ~/.bash_profile set your AWS access key and secret like so:

   export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XYZ123

   export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XYZ123
4. `cd` into the `bin` folder of the repo, there will be two files:

   `ec2-host` and `ec2-ssh`

copy them to your `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`.

Now you can do awesome stuff like:

```
$ ec2-host ZenWorker
ec2-999-xy-999-99.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

and

```
$ ec2-ssh ZenWorker
Connecting to ec2-999-xy-999-99.compute-1.amazonaws.com.
```

Note that in your regular shell scripts you can use backticks to call these global tools. I've timed these calls and they take between 0.25 and 0.5 second using an EC2 instance, so that's really the only downside. Perhaps you can live with the delay, or use the fact that public DNS only changes for an instance on reboot to work up a solution.

Note that these two programs are commandline scripts and you don't need any Python knowledge to use them. For PHP fans, or those that also want an easy way to `scp` files without knowing the changing public DNS, you can checkout [ec2dns](https://github.com/fruux/ec2dns).

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same situation once. I still dont have the expertise to solve it properly. My ugly solution was to use elb not really for load balancing but just for the endpoint.

But I think a good solution can be obtained by using [aws vpc](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/).

Comment: That can add up at $18.60 month minimally + $0.008 per GB Data processed. Thanks for discussing the option though. Will investigate  Amazon Virtual Private Cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another Ruby solution for [Updating Route 53 DNS from instance on AWS](https://gist.github.com/kixorz/5146008). You shouldn't reference raw 3rd party system IP addresses in your applications or server configurations.

Answer (score 0):

**you can change Ip  Address using Elastic Ip:
 You Can Do Using C# Code:**

```
 var associateRequest = new AssociateAddressRequest
            {
                 PublicIp = your Elastic Ip,
                 InstanceId = Your Instance Id Which You Assign
            };    
        amazonEc2Client.AssociateAddress(associateRequest);
```

**after That DeAssociate It.**

```
        var disAssociateRequest = new isassociateAddressRequest(publicIp.ElasticIpAddress1);
  AmazonEc2Client.DisassociateAddress(your Elastic Ip);
```

**your Public Ip Will Change**