# Changing IP address for Cloudera in EC2 EBS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip

I have cloudera installed in one **m1.large** instance . 
I was able install it successfully. 
But once i stop the instance and start it again next morning the IP changes and cloudera still refers to old IP and none of the services run . 
How can i solve this problem because i can not keep instance up whole day?

Since its for academic purpose and I don't have a budget  .

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't really have anything to do with Cloudera -- more the behavior of EC2 Instances.  The feature you're looking for is called an [Elastic IP Address](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html), which is a static IP address that you can assign to your EC2 instance. Elastic IP behavior has some differences in EC2-Classic and EC2-VPC, noted [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html#VPC_EIP_EC2_Differences). Most notably for you will be instance startup behavior regarding Elastic IP addresses, which I'll get to shortly.

You can find details on Elastic IP pricing [here](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/).  Note that while your first Elastic IP address (associated with a running instance is free), you will be charged by the hour for the time that your instance is offline and you still have the Elastic IP Address.  This rate is "$0.005 per Elastic IP address not associated with a running instance per hour on a pro rata basis." So not very expensive, but there is some expense to be aware of.

Another [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21609323/775544) has a couple of good answers on how to allocate the Elastic IP address on instance startup.  In EC2-Classic you will need to script it or do it manually.  In VPC the Elastic IP will remain associated with the instance. (I think you're still charged the fee, though, per this [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-ip-addressing.html) claiming that a small hourly fee is charged if an Elastic IP is associated with a stopped instance.)

---

If any expensive is prohibitive, I would recommend looking into [AWS Command Line Interface](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to get the new public IP of the EC2 instance on startup and writing a script to change that IP address in your configuration.

Comment: Cloudera refers private IP in EC2 . Will the private IP also will be same when restart or only public IP ?

Comment: @DeepeshShetty There is likewise no guarantee of private IPs remaining the same in EC2 on startup: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10733244/775544.  You can use VPC if you need to manage your private IPs more specifically, or script a solution to get the private IP on startup as I've suggested above for the public IP. For this use case, it sounds like you probably want to look into VPC addressing: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-ip-addressing.html

Answer (score 1):

You can setup your machine inside a [VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-vpc.html):

> By launching your instances into a VPC instead of EC2-Classic, you
>   gain the ability to:
>
> - Assign static private IP addresses to your instances that persist
>     across starts and stops